# Winapi c++, когда закрываю дочернее окно, завершается программа. В чем ошибка?

Tags: winapi, visual-c++

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <commctrl.h>
#include <winuser.h>
#include <windowsx.h>

static TCHAR szWindowClass[] = _T("DesktopApp");
static TCHAR szTitle[] = _T("Электронный журнал");

HINSTANCE hInst;                 

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

HWND hwndWindow;
    
wchar_t sext[100];
wchar_t sext2[100] = L"Введите текст";
wchar_t sext3[100] = L"Введите название прибора.";

EDITWORDBREAKPROCA Editwordbreakproca;

int WINAPI WinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,_In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,_In_ LPSTR lpCmdLine,_In_ int nCmdShow)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wcex;

    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wcex.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wcex.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wcex.hInstance = hInstance;
    wcex.hIcon = LoadIcon(wcex.hInstance, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wcex.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1);
    wcex.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wcex.lpszClassName = szWindowClass;
    wcex.hIconSm = LoadIcon(wcex.hInstance, IDI_APPLICATION);
    if (!RegisterClassEx(&wcex))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL,
            _T("Call to RegisterClassEx failed!"),
            _T("Windows Desktop Guided Tour"),
            NULL);
        return 1;
    }

    hInst = hInstance;

    HWND hWnd = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,szWindowClass,szTitle,WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,500, 500,NULL,NULL,hInstance,NULL);
    if (!hWnd)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL,_T("Call to CreateWindow failed!"),_T("Windows Desktop Guided Tour"),NULL);
        return 1;
    }
    ShowWindow(hWnd,nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);

    hwndWindow = CreateWindow (szWindowClass, L"окно2", WS_SYSMENU | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CAPTION, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 400, 300, hWnd, NULL, (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWLP_HINSTANCE), NULL);
```

// hwndWindow - дочернее окно при закрытии которого завершается вся программа... Как сделать чтобы после закрытии этого окна, программа не завершалась??

```
    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    return (int)msg.wParam;
}
```

Comment: Мне кажется, что для дочернего окна нужно регистрировать новый класс окна

Comment: А как вы закрытие окна обрабатываете в WndProc?